# How to process nulls in parallel routine in Datastage

Tags: c++, datastage

I have defined and tested a custom routine that processes data the way I want, but I also want to be able tor process null values passed into the field. No matter what I seem to try I am getting the following error when a null is passed into the routine.

**Field 'Data' from input dataset '0' is NULL. Record dropped.**

I have a catch in the routine to process a NULL passed into it, but my understanding is that Datastage does not store NULLs in the c-type standard. What do I need to do to process these nulls in the routine, and how can I stop datastage from dropping the record? I understand that I could just add NullToEmpty for this field, but we have 100s of jobs and columns, so I would prefer strongly to consolidate this.

For example, here is the c++ code for the routine. trimSpace is defined and works fine, so is omitted.

```
char * BlankToValue(char *InStr, char *RepStr)
{
    if ((InStr == NULL) || (InStr[0] == '\0'))                           // Check for null pointer at first character of input string.
    {
        return RepStr;                              // Return replacement string if true. This is to prevent unnecessary processing.
    } else
    {
        trimSpace(InStr);                         // Call previously established function.

        if (InStr[0] == '\0')                       // Checks first character of cleaned input string for null pointer.
        {
            return RepStr;                          // Return replacement string if true.
        } else
        {
            return InStr;                           // Return new input string if false.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should you be testing with IsNull() ?

Comment: Do you mean in the datastage job itself or is there a c++ library specific to Datastage that I'm unaware?